# Issue using willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle

Tags: javascript, symfony, internationalization, translation

In order to use translations in my JavaScript files I implemented the [willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle). I exactly followed the [repository documentation](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md):

1. I installed the bundle

   ```
   composer require "willdurand/js-translation-bundle:@stable"
   ```
2. I registred the new bundle

   ```
   // ...
   new Bazinga\Bundle\JsTranslationBundle\BazingaJsTranslationBundle(),
   ```
3. I set up the routes

   ```
   # app/config/routing.yml
   _bazinga_jstranslation:
       resource: "@BazingaJsTranslationBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml"
   ```
4. I added the locale to my `<html>` tag

   ```
   <html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">
   ```
5. I added three JavaScript files

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bazingajstranslation/js/translator.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('bazinga_jstranslation_js', { 'domain': 'MyBundle' }) }}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('bazinga_jstranslation_js', { 'domain': 'validators' }) }}"></script>
   ```

   ... where the first line calls the translator file from the bundle, the second line include the translation elements from my bundle and the third line calls the validator elements.
6. I dumped the translation files

   ```
   php app/console bazinga:js-translation:dump
   ```
7. And I include some translated elements in my code

   ```
   Translator.trans('key', { "foo" : "bar" }, 'MyBundle');
   ```

The curious thing: Everything works fine. But when I logout and login, instead of routing me to my regular start page, I get routed to the validator route (`http://my.domain.tld/translations/validators`) and the content of that file is shown:

```
(function (Translator) {
    Translator.fallback      = 'de';
    Translator.defaultDomain = 'MyBundle';
    // de
    Translator.add("This value should be false.", "Dieser Wert sollte false sein.", "validators", "de");
    // ...
})(Translator);
```

Now what is wrong here? I don't think that I misconfigured the bundle. So is this an actual bug of the bundle, or did I possibly misconfigure the bundle?

### Update

After I removed this line

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('bazinga_jstranslation_js', { 'domain': 'validators' }) }}"></script>
```

I get the same error but instead of being routed to `http://my.domain.tld/translations/validators` I'm being routed to `http://my.domain.tld/translations/MyBundle` and I'm being shown its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a security problem: The dumped JS (and JSON) translation files are located in the `/web/js/translations` folder and therefore should be excluded by the firewall. But they're actually routed via `/translations/`. So I had to add the `translations` path in the according `security.firewalls.dev.pattern` setting:

```
# security.yml
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_profiler|_wdt|css|js|translations)
            security: false
```

Note, that this not just applies for the `dev` environment, but also for `test` and `prod` environments, because

> the name `dev` for the firewall is because it was meant to cover the profiler and the web debug toolbar initially. It was then extended to cover assets as well without being renamed in the standard edition.